# Sharing Windows Folders on a Network... other PCs see but can't access

Tags: windows, network-shares, home-networking, windows-networking

I'm soooo tired of network setup issues. All I want to do is share a folder and all it's sub-folders so other PCs on my network can view and change this remote location.
Why is it that setting a dir to "shared" doesn't actually make it usable in any way? The other PC can see the fodler but is unable to actually open it and look inside. It seems *every* time I want to do this I go through some semi-random process of right clicking the folder and enabling sharing, then looking in the folder properties to add permissions and other sharing... and then I end up with some folders working but others will randomly block permission on certain files or sub-dirs.
I have 5 PCs in my local testing network and I cannot believe it should be this complicated... where is the simple "make this folder work on the network" option?!

I have a mixture of XP, Vista & W7 machines, but this seems common to all of them.

Comment: How about you save your sanctimonious ego-trip until you have something helpful to post? Fair enough to add a comment when you post an answer but taking time _just_ for that is pretty immature. Also I fail to see it's my problem if people don't give good answers... unlike some I only mark questions as answered when they _are_, not to boost my %.